# Different variable type declaration in Golang

Tags: variables, go, struct

Hi I'm just learning Go since the last view days, read some docs and noted that its something about defining struct or interface. Still cant get the difference between

```
var result []Struct
```

and

```
result := Struct{}
```

Is there particular docs I can refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `result` in the first example is a nil slice. The spec says that variables are [initialized to their zero values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) and that [zero value of a slice is nil](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value).

The `result` in the second example is a `Struct` value. It uses a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) and [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) value for a `Struct`.  The second example identical to

```
var result Struct
```

Perhaps you meant to write

```
result := []Struct{}
```

for the second example. This is a non-nil zero length slice. The expression `[]Struct{}` is a composite literal for an empty slice of `Struct`.